# Python tkinter checkbutton issue (unchecking the box calls the attached command)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have attached a function (comhelms) to my check button. It works normally by calling the function when I check the box. However, unchecking the box calls the function as well. How can I avoid this?

```
  i = Checkbutton(helmsframe, variable = helmscblist[i], command = comhelms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't prevent the callback from being called when unchecking your checkbutton. But inside the callback function, you can easily use the **associated variable** to know whether the box was just checked or unchecked:

```
var = tk.IntVar()

def cb():
    if var.get():
        print("box checked")
    else:
        print("box unchecked")

c = tk.Checkbutton(parent, variable=var, command=cb)
```